# CiviMail adds call to onbeforeunload function then throws "Illegal Characters" error over and over again

Tags: civimail

I recently upgraded to 4.6.2...All's well until I try to create a new mailing. Every time I start to compose a message from scratch, or use a template a javascript call to the 'onbeforeunload' function is inserted into the bottom of the message which causes an error box to pop-up reading

"Error Illegal characters in input (potential scripting attack)"

What is going on? I've tried using different wysiwyg and no wysiwyg with the same results. It doesn't happen in any other HTML field I can find in CiviCRM or Drupal, only when creating a new mail message but I can't save or send a message because every attempt causes the script to be added and the error to be triggered.

HELP!! This wasn't happening before the upgrade. But I'm stumped for a cause.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this doesn't exhibit on the demo sites and hasn't been reported by anyone else, my first suggestion is to disable extensions/plugins/customizations because this may not be originating from CiviCRM.

If that doesn't work, try the more detailed [troubleshooting javascript in CiviCRM](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850) guide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Knowing that this was a problem that no one else had described was very helpful. I started scrounging around in things unrelated to Drupal or CiviMail (I figured if it were a misbehaving module I wouldn't be the only one). Turned out to be a misbehaving browser plugin to prevent malicious popups that was so old I'd forgotten I even had it.